# How to have a navbar highlight the page you are in php

Tags: php, css, wordpress

So, I am trying to make a personal web site. The site i am making has a navigation bar in the header section. In that navbar i have a few links Home Blog About Contact-Me. I want to make it so that it checks what page you are in and adds the class active to the link i am currently on. example I am on the home page and the Home link has the class active. when i click on about, about NOW has the class active and home doesn't.

Comment: There are tutorials out there for this stuff. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This Code

```
.nav li.active a{
       color: #de990a !important;
}


<ul class="nav">

  <li <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'home.php') echo 'class="active"' ?>><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
  <li <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'blog.php') echo 'class="active"' ?>><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></li>
  <li <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'about.php') echo 'class="active"' ?>><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
  <li <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'contact.php') echo 'class="active"' ?>><a href="contact.php">Contact Me</a></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'active_nav_class' , 10 , 2);

function active_nav_class ($classes, $item) {
    if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){
        $classes[] = 'active ';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Active class will be added to the current nav item and you can add your css to the .active class.